# $F(M)$ as a $\text{Hom}_{R_1}(M,M)$-module for some functor $F:R_1-\text{mod}\rightarrow R_2-\text{mod}$

Tags: category-theory, modules

I'm trying to generalize one aspect of the accepted answer in: [$\text{Hom}(\mathbb{F}_p G, M)$ and $H^1(G,M)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231676/texthom-mathbbf-p-g-m-and-h1g-m)

Is the following statement correct?

> If:
>
> 1. $R_1$ and $R_2$ are rings;
> 2. $F:R_1-\text{mod}\rightarrow R_2-\text{Mod}$ is an additive functor;
> 3. $M \in R_1-\text{Mod}$.
>
> Then:
>
> 1. $F(M)$ is a $\text{Hom}_{R_1}(M,M)$-module where
> 2. the action of $\text{Hom}_{R_1}(M,M)$ on $F(M)$ is given by $f\cdot x=F(f)(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can see this easily by noting that the action of $F$ on endomorphism rings is a *ring* homomorphism, by virtue of the fact that $F$ is an additive functor: so in particular we get a ring homomorphism $\textrm{End}_{R_1} (M) \to \textrm{End}_{R_2}(F M)$. In fact more is true: the action of $\textrm{End}_{R_1} (M)$ on $F M$ will be $R_2$-linear. (Recall the fact that a left $R$-module $M$ is the same thing as an abelian group $M$ and a ring homomorphism $R \to \textrm{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$.)